# Writing Recursive Function in MIPS Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to write the following recursion in MIPS.

```
f(x) = 5, if x=0
f(x) = 2*f(x-1)+x, if x>0
```

Here is what I've done so far :

```
.data
    prompt_string: .asciiz "Enter the number: "
    
    result: .asciiz "The result is: "

.text
.globl main

main:
    li $v0,4
    la $a0, prompt_string
    syscall

    #get the number

    li $v0,5
    syscall

    # save the input

    move $a0,$v0

    jal function

    move $s7, $v1


    li $v0,4
    la $a0, result
    syscall

    
    move $a0,$s7
    li $v0,1
    syscall

    li $v0,10
    syscall



function:

    # save some stack

    addi $sp, $sp, -12

    sw $ra, 0($sp)
    sw $s0, 4($sp)
    sw $s1, 8($sp)


    add $s0,$zero, $a0
    beq $s0,$zero, return_5

    addi $a0,$s0,-1

    jal function

    sll $v0,$v0,1
    add $s1, $s0,$v0

    move $v1, $s1

    





return_5:
    li $v0,5
    j terminate


terminate:
    lw $ra, 0($sp)
    lw $s0, 4($sp)
    lw $s1, 8($sp)
    

    addi $sp,$sp,12

    jr $ra
```

My code works for x=0 and x=1 but it fails to output the correct result for the other values. For example, it outputs 16 when x=6, outputs 15 when x=5.

I could not find any solution. Where is the problem? How can I fix that?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your non-5 return falls through into `return_5`. Also it's unclear where you want to put the result, `$v0` or `$v1`. You put the 5 into `$v0` but the caller uses `$v1`. As is, I find it hard to believe your claim that it works for `x=0` since the `5` is not loaded into `$v1`. I tested, it prints `0` not `5`.

Comment: @Jester actually, firstly i was only using v0 but the return answer was always 5, even though s1 holds  the correct value for x=1. That's why I used v1.

Comment: You should stick to `$v0` as that is the convention. While you could use `$v1` what definitely does not work is mixing the two as you have done.

Comment: Using v1 is inappropriate for the return value, use v0 only.

Comment: Why multiply the recursive result x 2?  That's not in the function definitions in the text.

Comment: You don't need s1 at all, since you're not using it live across a call.  Just sum to v0 there.

Comment: @ErikEidt ah I'm sorry I have edited the recursive function in the question. I forgot to add the multiplication in the question. I've done your suggestions but now it only outputs 5 regardless of the input.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Now, just follow the rest of the advice given above.